# Can I use wso2:vault-lookup in a data source?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have Data Service Project and I am trying to use de wso2-vault in order to save my password and user, the problem is the ESB is getting the parameter as a string so not resolve like a exression. Is there any  way to do that?

**pom.xml**

```
 <properties>
     <driverClassName>mydrive</driverClassName>
     <url>myurl</url>
     <user>{wso2:vault-lookup('user')}</user>
     <password>{wso2:vault-lookup('password')}</password>
</properties>
```

**datasource.xml**

```
<datasource>
    <name>Connection</name>
    <description>Connection</description>
    <jndiConfig useDataSourceFactory="false">
        <name>ConJNDI1</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
            <driverClassName>${driverClassName}</driverClassName>
            <url>${url}</url>
            <username>${user}</username>
            <password>${password}</password>
        </configuration>
    </definition>
</datasource>
```

**Error in Integrator console:**

```
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Nested Exception:-
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "{wso2:vault-lookup('user')}"
```

Is that posible? I am using the version 6.6.0.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This problem was reported some time ago:
[Provide WSO2 vault-lookup functionality for Data sources](https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/5335)

Was fixed, merged:
[Add vault-lookup support to Data Services](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-data/pull/303)
but for use that, you need to update libs org.wso2.carbon.dataservices....jar's